# how do I successfully upscale a bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am using createBitmap to recreate an upscaled image but get the below error message.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
```

When using createScaledBitmap I get an out of memory error. I have tried possible solutions from other forums but not had any luck.

```
public Bitmap scaleToActualAspectRatio(Bitmap bitmap) {

        Bitmap newbitmap = null;

try {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaledWidth, scaledHeight);

        newbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, matrix, false);
                    //bitmap.recycle();

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

return newbitmap;
    }
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this function work for you, one more think scale value is floating here, you pass the height and width of the required bitmap. Read comment carefully.

```
public Bitmap scaleToActualAspectRatio(Bitmap bitmap) {

            Bitmap newBitmap = null;

            try {

                //width = 500 and height = 500
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                int newWidth = 1200;
                int newHeight = 1200;

                // calculate the scale - in this case = 2.4f
                float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
                float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

                // create matrix for the manipulation
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                // resize the bit map 2.4f, 2.4f
                matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

                // recreate the new Bitmap
                newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, matrix, true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return newBitmap;
        }
```

Comment: I am still getting the error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference

Comment: why are you recycler your bitmap? take one simple bitmap and just passing bitmap into this function it will be work perfectly.